# How to align input fields in forms without using &nbsp; so that they start at the same vertical position regardless of the size of the label?

Tags: html, forms

I am new to html. This is a very simple question. I am dealing with forms. I want all the input text fields to start at the same x-axis point regardless of the size of the label. I want the labels to be left aligned and all the text fields to start at the same x-axis point.I don't want to use tables or "&nbsp". Is there a simple solution or Should I use separate divisions for labels and input fields? I don't mind using css but I prefer it to be simple.

```
<form>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="n1"><br>
<label>Phone No.</label>
<input type="text" name="p1">
</form>
```

I want "n1" and "p1" to start at the same x-axis point.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your page:

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:80px
}
```

Check here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o6qoLqc/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use paragraph tags for every input element.

```
<p><input type="text" name="your name"></p>
<p><input type="email" name="your email"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I use <p> tag the input fields goes to the next line. But I don't want it to be on the next line. I want the name and n1 on same line. In the next line I want Phone No. and p1. But n1 and p1 should start on same x-axis point. Can you understand what I am saying?

Comment: your comment is lil confusing :(

Comment: well as much as I can understand I can suggest you is:<p>Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="your name"></p><p>Email:&nbsp;<input type="email" name="your email"></p> Try this.